# SQL CASE SELECT return char

Tags: sql

I have 6 tables: LS_CLIENT_INSEE_A, B, C , etc. Each table contains only 1 field: INSEE.

I just want to know if my input exists in one of these tables and return the corresponding letter from the table name (A,B,C etc).

Is there another why to rewrite this:

```
@TheInsee int
AS
BEGIN
declare @Zone char(1)

declare @CountA int
declare @CountB int
declare @CountC int
declare @CountD int
declare @CountF int
declare @CountP int

SELECT @CountA = COUNT(*) FROM LS_CLIENT_INSEE_A WHERE NO_INSEE = @TheInsee
SELECT @CountB = COUNT(*) FROM LS_CLIENT_INSEE_B WHERE NO_INSEE = @TheInsee
SELECT @CountC = COUNT(*) FROM LS_CLIENT_INSEE_C WHERE NO_INSEE = @TheInsee
SELECT @CountD = COUNT(*) FROM LS_CLIENT_INSEE_D WHERE NO_INSEE = @TheInsee
SELECT @CountF = COUNT(*) FROM LS_CLIENT_INSEE_F WHERE NO_INSEE = @TheInsee
SELECT @CountP = COUNT(*) FROM LS_CLIENT_INSEE_P WHERE NO_INSEE = @TheInsee

set @Zone = 
      CASE 
         WHEN @CountA >  0   THEN 'A'
         WHEN @CountB >  0   THEN 'B'
         WHEN @CountC >  0   THEN 'C'   
         WHEN @CountD >  0   THEN 'D' 
         WHEN @CountF >  0   THEN 'F' 
         WHEN @CountP >  0   THEN 'P'         
      END  

END
```

Is above query the best way of achieving this?

Thanks you in advance,
Stev

Comment: I suggest you consider normalising this database!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work by stopping the select once it finds a hit, worst case will still be when it's in none of them.

Note: assuming SQL Server (difference being the `TOP 1` compared to `LIMIT 1`):

```
 @TheInsee int
AS
BEGIN
declare @Zone char(1)

SELECT @Zone = 
      CASE 
         WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM LS_CLIENT_INSEE_A WHERE NO_INSEE = @TheInsee) >  0   THEN 'A'
         WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM LS_CLIENT_INSEE_B WHERE NO_INSEE = @TheInsee) >  0   THEN 'B'
         WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM LS_CLIENT_INSEE_C WHERE NO_INSEE = @TheInsee) >  0   THEN 'C' 
         WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM LS_CLIENT_INSEE_D WHERE NO_INSEE = @TheInsee) >  0   THEN 'D'
         WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM LS_CLIENT_INSEE_F WHERE NO_INSEE = @TheInsee) >  0   THEN 'F'
         WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM LS_CLIENT_INSEE_P WHERE NO_INSEE = @TheInsee) >  0   THEN 'P'       
      END  
END
```

The `TOP 1 1` is a shortcut to prevent it from scanning the entire table which is important if `NO_INSEE` is not indexed and the table is large, it will stop when it gets the first hit and not continue to scan the entire table.

Comment: It will stop processing additional tables after it finds a hit but you would need to use `EXISTS` to stop processing the current table after it finds a hit.

Comment: True, without knowing the RDMS I can't decide if we should use `SELECT TOP 1 1` or `SELECT 1 .. LIMIT 1' is there a general accepted way for doing this without knowing which RDMS?

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of all `@CountX` variables and do the following:

(SQL [EXISTS()](http://EXISTS) effectively checks whether at least single row exits and return immediately, so it would be faster then COUNT(*) because exit when first row is found)

```
SELECT @Zone = CASE WHEN EXISTS (
                           SELECT * FROM LS_CLIENT_INSEE_A 
                           WHERE NO_INSEE = @TheInsee 
                           )
                THEN 'A' END

...
```